# elasticsearch restart leave unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to restart elasticsearch cluster nodes because of some timeout exceptions 
I did restart the nodes one by one there are 5 data nodes in cluster 
But when I did that it leave some shards unassigned and I have no replicas
There is nothing help full in logs.
Can I get some help to know why these shards remain unassigned and any solution
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231614/quick-recovery-after-node-restart-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Run this against your cluster, should rerun the command once shards have relocated however change the false parameter to `true` -

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d ' {"index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": false}'
```

Answer (score -1):

yeah, you will find some shards as unassigned. Give them some time to get allocated after the cluster gets restarted